# Crash Dump 3564

Tags: matlab, debugging, crash-dumps, psychtoolbox

I'm using GUI and playing sound through psychotoolbox and have this error:

> *Matlab Crash ...\matlab_crash_dump.3564-1: Segmentation violation detected > at Sat May ...
>   Configuration:   Crash Decoding  : Disabled   Default Encoding:
>   windows-1252   MATLAB Root     : C:\Program Files\MATLAB12a\R2012a
>   MATLAB Version  : 7.14.0.739 (R2012a)   Operating System: Microsoft
>   Windows XP   Processor ID    : x86 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 10,
>   GenuineIntel   Virtual Machine : Java 1.6.0_17-b04 with Sun
>   Microsystems Inc. Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM mixed mode   Window
>   System   : Version 5.1 (Build 2600: Service Pack 3)
>
> Fault Count: 1 Abnormal termination: Segmentation violation Register
>   State (from fault):    ...
>   Stack Trace (from fault): If this problem is reproducible, please
>   submit a Service Request via:*

Any way to avoid this error?
Thanks!

Comment: How often does this error occur?  Is it reproducible?  What code / actions do you do in MATLAB to get this error?

Comment: I'm making keyboard and mouse event when this error occured , I would say it didn't appears often, in total 4 times on 15 hours of trial on matlab. There was a notice " this error is reproductible".

Comment: Does it occur anywhere else in any of your other programs?  Do you sometimes get random error messages from your other programs and they shut down randomly?  It sounds like a memory problem related to your RAM.